# Using another table in BigQuery Regex

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I would like to map a string column to a category based on a regular expression match.

Is it possible to use another bigquery table containing the regular expressions and corresponding category for this? This would make it easier for me to update only a table when adding new categories/updating the regex, instead of having to update all queries that would use this lookup.

Query:

```
CASE
 -- Use the entries from another table here
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(string_to_check, cat1regex) THEN cat1
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(string_to_check, cat2regex) THEN cat2
 etc.
END
```

Mapping table:

```
Regex          category
pagex|pagey    xy
pagez|page1    z1
```

It's also possible there is another simple way to do something similar that I'm not thinking of, answers pointing those out are welcome too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the feeling that a function might be more appropriate here, because you need to access the various regex within a single `CASE` expression.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'm now looking into user-defined functions and that seems the way I should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  string_to_check,
  MAX(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(string_to_check, reg), category, NULL)) AS category
FROM yourTable
CROSS JOIN mappingTable
GROUP BY string_to_check
```

You can test / play with it using below dummy date from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `mappingTable` AS (
  SELECT r'pagex|pagey' AS reg, 'xy' AS category UNION ALL
  SELECT r'pagez|page1', 'z1'
),
`yourTable` AS (
  SELECT string_to_check
  FROM UNNEST(["pagex.com", "pagez@example.org", "page.example.net"]) AS string_to_check
)
SELECT
  string_to_check,
  MAX(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(string_to_check, reg), category, NULL)) AS category
FROM yourTable
CROSS JOIN mappingTable
GROUP BY string_to_check
```